# Is it possible to create a custom flag for a system binary?

Tags: linux, command-line, ssh, shell, flag

I have [several SSH configurations](https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config) in the file `~/.ssh/config` on my local Linux machine.

Is it possible to assign a new flag to an existing binary like `/usr/bin/ssh` such that I can execute `ssh -l` to get a list of available connections (for example)?

I know that I can `cat ~/.ssh/config` (or similar), but I'm wondering **specifically whether it's possible to add or alias a flag on a system binary.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not intrinsically, no – there are, however some workarounds, including –

1. Get the source code, modify it, recompile, and use your own version of the software.
2. Create a wrapper (which could be a script or a shell function) that looks what it gets on the command line and passes options through and/or handles additional functionality.

These typically involve renaming the program, or ensuring that your version occurs earlier in your search path than the original.